# how to get the URL to connect local system to remote repository through TotoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I m new to Tortoise SVN .i want to work in a team.i have installed  Svn1ClickSetup-1.3.3 in my windows7, and created a repository in a new folder.and i want to know how can i connect to remote system ,how to get an URL and how to set authentication to them.

Please any body can help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't address the question directly but you are using an **extremely** old release (*seven years*) of Subversion and really ought to be using a current version. Svn1ClickSetup was seemingly abandoned 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure you svn to obtain a generic url which will look something like this

```
http://e880/svn/
```

You can append the folder names to this url.Take this url and right click in any folder to SVN Checkout and paste the url and done.

Comment: Thanks Sandy for response,

Comment: could u please help me to create that generic url and how to configure them?   Sorry if its a very silly question,i am very new to this. looking for ur response..

Comment: [Check this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html). Hope you will get enough information

Comment: [and this too](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/TortoiseSVN%20instructions)